# Permission denied, are you root?

Tags: apt

I get this error whenever I try to install programs using the terminal:

```
home@ubuntu:~$ apt-get install myunity
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?
```

Also I'm unable to install updates using the terminal.

Comment: This isn't a duplicate, same error, but different reasons.

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get update`

Comment: i think your gui update manager is open while you running apt-get update and one thing you must be super user or use sudo before using apt-get update

Comment: Do you even own that computer, if yes then you need to show that by being the root owner (**sudo**) before any installation please

Comment: See also http://askubuntu.com/questions/427479/unable-to-lock-the-administration-directory-var-lib-dpkg-are-you-root

Comment: @AvinashRaj That solve things but it s not a good strategy. I could do this without root before and actually building docker containers do not use sudo all the time

Answer (score 145, accepted):

The solution is to read the error message: **are you root?**

Use `sudo` to run a command with root privileges, like this:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: /bin/sh: 49: sudo: not found eehm what to do here?

Comment: @Suisse you’re not using bash which is pretty uncommon so the first question is why, secondly you might want to try simply typing /bin/bash to get into bash

Comment: I am using the terminal of a docker image. from the docker dashboard. by doing /bin/bash I got into bash (different colors and highlighting) but I still get the error: E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), are you root?

Comment: @Suisse if you're using Docker it's a Docker question more than an Ubuntu question. It may depend on your container but likely you can specify that you want to be root when you enter the container, like `docker exec -u root -it <container-id> /bin/bash`

Answer (score 31):

According to the [community documentation about using the terminal](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal),

> #### sudo: Executing Commands with Elevated Privileges
>
> 1. Most of the following commands will need to be prefaced with the **sudo** command. This elevates privileges to the root-user administrative level temporarily, which is necessary when working with directories or files not owned by your user account. When using sudo you will be prompted for your password. Only users with sudo (administrative) privileges will be able to use this command. You should **never** use normal sudo to start graphical applications as Root (Please see [RootSudo](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo) for more information on using sudo correctly.)

So, because apt-get installs software and thus affects the system, you need to use the `sudo` command to give yourself administrator privilages.

Thus, you command should be `sudo apt-get install myunity`

If you want to update your system, run

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

This will update your system's package database and then install any upgrades.

Comment: This does't help in getting rid of the error: `unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?`

Comment: This one worked for me. You shouldn't run both commands in one line as it was giving me same above error. I ran it separately and it's doing something. Let's see how it goes.

Answer (score 13):

Before running any administrative task: installing, removing, changing system wide preferences, etc. you need to be `root`. This is specially true for `apt-get`. The message itself tells you where the problem is:

> are you root?

If you are not `root`, the `install` command will not work at all.

The way to fix this is using `sudo` before the command:

```
➜  ~  apt-get update
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?
➜  ~  sudo apt-get update
Fetched 616 kB in 25s (23.9 kB/s)
```

As you can notice, it completed without problems when I used `sudo`. If you have any `open (13: Permission denied)` it is almost sure that you are not `root` and need to use `sudo`.

Comment: Thanks for the help gents,as I have not set root I didn't think I'd need to use sudo but for me it's all a learning experience.Just wish you could stipulate updates in terminal

Answer (score 4):

Try with

```
sudo apt-get update
```

If you still get lock error try this command
It will give the process detail

```
ps -e | grep -e apt -e adept | grep -v grep
```

Then kill the process using process ID
then execute the update command

And also u can delete this file your problem will solve

```
rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock
```

Comment: Remember to close down the Software Center before using apt-get. Or else the updater gets locked.

Comment: The lock exists to protect your repository configuration files. Killing processes and removing lock files without care can lead to a badly misconfigured system. This answer is really DANGEROUS. Before removing a lock file you have to be triple sure that the process holding it has closed, or crashed, or whatever. The correct answer is @braiam 's one.

Comment: No such file or directory: `/var/lib/dpkg/lock`

Comment: The updater held the lock, so I could not run `apt-get install`. I had to wait until the update finishes (couple of minutes only), then it worked,

Answer (score 4):

just run

`sudo apt-get update`

sudo is for running it as super user

Answer (score 2):

Just read the error output: `are you root?` because you are not. As a regular user you don't have enough privileges to install packages.

Prepend `sudo` to the command to elevate the privileges. Provided that account has sudo privileges that will work.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error and in my case I had to remove
`noexec` on `/var` in `/etc/fstab`

which works fine on my CentOS, Fedora and Alpine Linux