# Terminal fills with `y` when I answer `yes` to "Are you root?" when installing packages. What's the correct answer?

Tags: command-line, apt, package-management, sudo, root

What is the answer to the question "Are you root?" asked by APT?

I was installing the restricted extras package when I got this message after typing my password.

I typed `yes` in answer to the question and now the terminal is filling up with the letter `y`!

What should I do?

Comment: Related: [Permission denied, are you root?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223484/permission-denied-are-you-root) This question is somewhat different, though, in that it arises from the assumption that a *reply* is intended, and in that a core part of it is the accidental invocation of the infinitely looping `yes` command. (I was probably wrong to have voted to close this as a duplicate before.)

Answer (score 10):

"Are you root?" from `apt-get` is not expecting you to type an answer - by doing so you have accidentally executed the command `yes`, which does just what it says

```
DESCRIPTION
       Repeatedly output a line with all specified STRING(s), or `y'.
```

You can stop it just by typing `Ctrl-C` in the terminal.

The "Are you root?" question is just meant to give you a hint why the command you just tried failed i.e. because you didn't have sufficient privileges to run it, and should have used `sudo`

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

Answer (score 2):

As [steeldriver says](https://askubuntu.com/a/342000/22949), this is not a question that you answer interactively. Instead, it is a reminder that you must run commands like `apt-get` and `aptitude` as root, for package installation to succeed.

If you're not running it as root or are not sure if you are--in particular, if you are not [using `sudo`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo)--then you should run it as root with `sudo`. See this question for more information:

- [Permission denied, are you root?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223484/error-when-enter-a-command-permission-denied-are-you-root)

If you *are* using `sudo` but still get that error, that's strange. There are some similar errors can occur when permission to access a lock file is denied due to another concurrently running package management utility or stale locks (that continue existing after the utility they represent is no longer running). So some of the answers here may help:

- [Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/) is another process using it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15433/how-do-i-fix-a-could-not-get-lock-var-lib-dpkg-lock-problem)

If none of this helps, then you'll have to provide more information. In particular, to get better answers, you should add the complete and exact text from the Terminal, including the lines showing commands you are running (and especially the command or commands that result in the "are you root" message), to your question, by *editing your question*.