# apt-get update says I have not permission

Tags: 14.04, apt

lately whenever i try to update through the terminal I get this message

```
E: could not open lock file /var/lib/apt/lists/lock  - open (13: permission denied)
E: unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
E: could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock  - open (13: permission denied)
E: unable to lock administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?
```

I am using ubuntu 14.04.1 and apt-get had been working just fine until now

Comment: here you go: http://askubuntu.com/questions/223484/permission-denied-are-you-root

Comment: Did you run `sudo` before your command? And do you have root privileges?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To run such command you need special permission.

Use `sudo`, but be carefull. It may ask for a password, that is the root password.

Comment: `sudo` will ask for the *user's* password - not the root password