# unable to fix and install packages on Xubuntu

Tags: system-installation

this is the code that keeps coming up.

```
brian@brian-Satellite-C655D:~$ apt-get -f install
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?
```

Yes, I am the admin and root on here.

Comment: Can you try with `sudo apt-get -f install`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Permission denied, are you root?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/223484/permission-denied-are-you-root)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `sudo` to install packages, so please use:

```
sudo apt-get -f install package
```

If You will have issues with that, You can do it using `sudo -i` command, but keep in mind that You may break Your system if You will do things with the root privileges.

If Your user is added to `sudoers`, You will still have to use `sudo` command and provide password for Your actions.

`sudo` will elevate Your command with higher privileges, keep in mind that granting `sudo` rights to a command makes it **powerful** and may harm Your system if is not used right.

I encourage to read this article: https://wiki.debian.org/sudo
It's always better to know more, especially when You are using Linux.

Key for not breaking linux systems is a consciously use of each command.