# Ubuntu 18.04 stuck in login loop due to unmet dependencies

Tags: dependencies, 18.04

I tried to upgrade from Ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04 using `sudo do-release-upgrade -d`
Everything was downloaded without any problem but ran into error while extracting and upgrading. I tried rebooting but now it is stuck in login loop.
I tried to correct dependencies but it didn't work.
[image]

Comment: you need `sudo apt-get -f install` (you didn't have sudo), plus try `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` (it doesn't have the restrictions of upgrade).  If you still get problems you need to check your sources.list file (https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libc-bin & https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libc6 as I agree with error messages)

Comment: I have used `sudo apt-get -f install` as well. Plus, `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` is also giving same error

Comment: I would look in your `sources.list` file (maybe `grep bionic /etc/apt/sources.list`) and expect to see something missing.   eg. my own shows `deb http://[redacted-mirror]/ bionic main multiverse universe restricted`  (you may not have all, but look for 'main' esp., likewise bionic-updates, bionic-security..)

Comment: I already have these. The problem is due to unmet dependencies which I am unable to get.

Comment: the bionic version of libc-bin (https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/libc-bin) has a rule that libc <<2.28 so 2.27 complies.   Your error message says <2.24 which is a xenial condition (https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/libc-bin). Your `sources.list` file isn't correct. If you `grep xenial /etc/apt/sources.list` you should get no results, but I bet you do due to errors in your sources.list file (# or commented out lines are okay)      the same grep but with bionic (18.04) should get many many lines (my prior comment where I only listed 1 of the many lines you'd see)

Comment: No results for xenial, and there are results for bionic

Comment: Can you please add `lsb_release -a`, and `grep "^deb.*bionic" /etc/apt/sources.list` to your question (edit it and add the commands and results there please). To me it still reads as if you have errors in your sources.list file(s). This grep only displays lines beginning in 'deb' followed by 'bionic'   (*Sorry, as I realize you've said this is your error all along - I can't think of any other cause*)

Comment: `lsb_release -a` is showing that I have bionic installed, but login screen is of xenial. I think I messed up and ended between both. I will go with a fresh install now.  Thanks for your efforts :)

Comment: Reviewers - please read the whole screenshot... it's not a duplicate of that!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Permission denied, are you root?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223484/permission-denied-are-you-root)

Comment: See the second last line. I think you should use "apt-mark showhold" to see if some packages are held. You can unhold them, then try "sudo apt-get -f install"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu gets stuck in a login loop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop)

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by logging in via command prompt then entering the command:

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

This installed the correct NVIDIA GPU drivers and then it worked fine after restart.

Comment: Saved the day for me. Thank you so much