# Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (2: No such file or directory)

Tags: 16.04, apt, updates, dpkg

I am trying to run `sudo apt-get upgrade` but it is showing the below error message:

```
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (2: No such file or directory)
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), are you root?
```

**Here are the solutions I have tried :**

1. I have tried, "sudo apt-get update"
2. I have also tried to delete the locked files using the commands:

   ```
   sudo rm -r /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend
   sudo rm -rf /var/lib/dpkg/lock
   ```

   but it is showing the error that "no so such file or directory".
3. I tried to kill all the running process using the command:

   ```
   ps aux | grep -i apt    
   sudo kill -9 <process id>
   sudo killall apt apt-get
   ```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: What is the output of `ls -l /vat/lib/dpkg/`? Looks like something is missing.

Comment: it is showing the error message: ls: cannot access '/vat/lib/dpkg/': No such file or directory

Comment: Oh sorry for the typo. It's `ls -l /var/lib/dpkg/`.

Comment: same error message .. : ls: cannot access '/var/lib/dpkg/': No such file or directory

Comment: Is it a 32bit or 64 bit installation?

Comment: 64 bit.........

Comment: Try this `sudo mkdir -p /var/lib/dpkg/{alternatives,info,parts,triggers,updates}; sudo touch /var/lib/dpkg/status;  sudo apt install dpkg`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Permission denied, are you root?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223484/permission-denied-are-you-root)

Answer (score 1):

The right solution is pasted below, run the below commands and it should fix the problem.

```
sudo mkdir -p /var/lib/dpkg/{alternatives,info,parts,triggers,updates}

sudo cp /var/backups/dpkg.status.0 /var/lib/dpkg/status

apt-get download dpkg

sudo dpkg -i dpkg*.deb

apt-get download base-files

sudo dpkg -i base-files*.deb

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get check
```

Comment: it worked perfectly, should be an accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

You most likely have another process that is using the package manager.

Close any other terminal instances and any GUI package managers. If you are not sure which process/program currently has those privileges, a reboot should fix the problem.

Comment: thanks for the response.. but still not working..