# Permission denied while trying to install abd using apt-get

Tags: apt, software-installation, permissions

I am getting permission denied errors while running `apt-get install adb`. This is what I'm getting:

[image]

Prior to these commands, two commands of update and upgrade ran successfully which were

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Permission denied, are you root?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223484/permission-denied-are-you-root) The error in the screenshot has nothing to do with Android Studio or the device. It is related to APT and privileges.

Answer (score 1):

You need root privileges to install this package. Try:

```
sudo apt-get install adb
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to kill the process that is blocking you from installing `adb` or other package. Try this:

```
$ sudo killall apt apt-get
```

After that, the problem should be solved. If it does not work, try some of the other methods described in details in this  [tutorial link](https://itsfoss.com/could-not-get-lock-error/)

Comment: Killing processes without inspecting the situation is, IMHO, "overkill"

Comment: ok, then find the responsible process: `ps aux | grep -i apt` and kill it `sudo kill <process_id>` . Reference: same link.