# Permission denied errors when trying to update Kubuntu 20.04

Tags: apt, permissions, 20.04

```
Reading package lists... Done
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/cache/apt/pkgcache.bin - RemoveCaches (13: Permission denied)
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/cache/apt/srcpkgcache.bin - RemoveCaches (13: Permission denied)
```

Comment: What command have you run in the terminal ? In order to update the system you have to have the root access . Try running " sudo apt upgrade " .

Comment: Try `sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/lock`, see if that works without error, and then eventually run `sudo apt upgrade` and re-try.

Comment: Related: [Permission denied, are you root?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223484/permission-denied-are-you-root) I'm not sure if this is that problem or not, since the error messages here don't say "are you root?" As @ParsaMousavi says, please **[edit]** this to show the exact command or commands that you ran that produced the output you've shown. Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Permission denied, are you root?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223484/permission-denied-are-you-root)

Answer (score 2):

Like [Parsa Mousavi said](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1247202/permission-denied-errors-when-trying-to-update-kubuntu-20-04/1247207#comment2103668_1247202), it looks like you don't have administrator privileges. Try running it on the default user you created while installing (if you are not on it already) and use `sudo`:

```bsh
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
```

I'm guessing you did `apt update` instead of `sudo apt update`.

If a command outputs `Permission Denied`, try adding `sudo` before it.