# Problem with lock files while installing Vulkan

Tags: dpkg, lock, vulkan

I am trying to install Vulkan on Ubuntu 20.04 by following the steps given on this website: https://linuxconfig.org/install-and-test-vulkan-on-linux. I am following the steps for AMD, not NVIDIA. When I run the line: `# apt install libvulkan1 mesa-vulkan-drivers vulkan-utils`, however, I receive the following errors:

```
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), are you root?
```

What do these mean, and how can I fix them?

Comment: Are you *actually* running the command from a root shell (as implied by the `#` prompt)? If not, see [Permission denied, are you root?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223484/permission-denied-are-you-root)

Comment: I ran it with sudo and it worked. Thanks!

Comment: It did, thanks!

Comment: How do I mark this as solved?

Comment: You can vote to *Close* it as a duplicate of the linked Q&A