# Following error pops up, randomly, not sure what is causing it, and how to solve it

Tags: apt, permissions, 21.10

[image: The error message]

```
❯ apt-get -oDebug::pkgAcquire::Worker=1 update
Reading package lists... Error!
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
E: can not open /var/lib/apt/lists/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_impish-security_InRelease - fopen (13: Permission denied)
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
```

The error pops up once a day, it disappears if i reboot my computer. It does not seem to be task specific, but i am usually watching youtube when this happens.
I will attach my system config below, if you need any more info, please let me know.
[image]

Edit: Ran `sudo apt update` following is the output

```
[sudo] password for dope: 
Hit:1 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish InRelease                     
Hit:2 https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com stable InRelease          
Hit:3 https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian stable InRelease                           
Hit:4 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable InRelease     
Hit:5 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates InRelease  
Hit:6 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-backports InRelease
Get:7 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-security InRelease [110 kB]
Get:8 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-security/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [9,204 B]
Get:9 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-security/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [2,312 B]
Fetched 122 kB in 4s (30.4 kB/s)              
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
7 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.

~ took 13s 
❯ apt list --upgradable
Listing... Done
libruby2.7/impish-updates,impish-security 2.7.4-1ubuntu3.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.7.4-1ubuntu3]
linux-generic-hwe-20.04/impish-updates 5.13.0.27.37 amd64 [upgradable from: 5.13.0.25.36]
linux-headers-generic-hwe-20.04/impish-updates 5.13.0.27.37 amd64 [upgradable from: 5.13.0.25.36]
linux-image-generic-hwe-20.04/impish-updates 5.13.0.27.37 amd64 [upgradable from: 5.13.0.25.36]
linux-libc-dev/impish-updates 5.13.0-27.29 amd64 [upgradable from: 5.13.0-25.26]
linux-modules-nvidia-470-generic-hwe-20.04/impish-updates 5.13.0-27.29 amd64 [upgradable from: 5.13.0-25.26]
ruby2.7/impish-updates,impish-security 2.7.4-1ubuntu3.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.7.4-1ubuntu3]
```

Comment: No problem there .. then please rub the upgrade it self: `sudo apt upgrade`

Comment: You need to use the command with `sudo`. See: [Permission denied, are you root?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223484/permission-denied-are-you-root)

Comment: I am not sure, how to check if it worked or not. Because, I don't even know why/when the error happens, it randomly appears in my top-bar. I am not running any command or installing anything when this error pops up. I just assume, it the software centre doing something in the background.